# How to retrieve data from sqlite file

Tags: android, sqlite, search

I am doing a search operation.I created a DBadapter. I am only able to manually insert values and perform the search. But i want to insert data from an sqlite file.How to proceed? Should I place that sqlite file in assets folder? PLease tell me how proceed. Basically i want to search the data from the sqlite file.

Here is my main activity code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    searchView.setOnCloseListener(this);

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    AssetManager manager = this.getAssets();
    mDbHelper = new CustomersDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open(); 

    mDbHelper.deleteAllCustomers();
    //Add some Customer data as a sample
    mDbHelper.createCustomer("PIZZA1", "Piz", "1107 West Ada", "", "Los Angeles");
    mDbHelper.createCustomer("PIZZA2", "Pizza Hut", "1562 West ", "", "Los Angeles");
    mDbHelper.createCustomer("SUB4", "Subway", "504 West ", "", "Los Angeles");
}
```

Here is DBAdapter:

```
public class CustomersDbAdapter 
{
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "rowid";
    public static final String KEY_CUSTOMER = "customer";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS1 = "address1";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS2 = "address2";
    public static final String KEY_CITY = "city";
    public static final String KEY_SEARCH = "searchData";

    private static final String TAG = "CustomersDbAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CustomerData";
    private static final String FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE = "CustomerInfo";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    //Create a FTS3 Virtual Table for fast searches
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE + " USING fts3(" +
    KEY_CUSTOMER + "," +
    KEY_NAME + "," +
    KEY_ADDRESS1 + "," +
    KEY_ADDRESS2 + "," +
    KEY_CITY + "," +
    //KEY_STATE + "," +
    //KEY_ZIP + "," +
    KEY_SEARCH + "," +
    " UNIQUE (" + KEY_CUSTOMER + "));";


    private final Context mCtx;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.w(TAG, DATABASE_CREATE);
        //db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public CustomersDbAdapter(Context ctx) 
{
    this.mCtx = ctx;
}

public CustomersDbAdapter open() throws SQLException
{
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    if (mDbHelper != null) {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }
}


public long createCustomer(String customer, String name, String address1, String address2, String city) {

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    String searchValue =     customer + " " + 
                            name + " " + 
                            address1 + " " + 
                            city + " "  
                         //   state + " " + zipCode
                            ;
    initialValues.put(KEY_CUSTOMER, customer);
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_ADDRESS1, address1);
    initialValues.put(KEY_ADDRESS2, address2);
    initialValues.put(KEY_CITY, city);
    //initialValues.put(KEY_STATE, state);
    //initialValues.put(KEY_ZIP, zipCode);
    initialValues.put(KEY_SEARCH, searchValue);

    return mDb.insert(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}


public Cursor searchCustomer(String inputText) throws SQLException {
    Log.w(TAG, inputText);
    String query = "SELECT docid as _id," + 
    KEY_CUSTOMER + "," +
    KEY_NAME + "," +
    "(" + KEY_ADDRESS1 + "||" + 
    "(case when " + KEY_ADDRESS2 +  "> '' then '\n' || " + KEY_ADDRESS2 + " else '' end)) as " +  KEY_ADDRESS +"," +
    KEY_ADDRESS1 + "," +
    KEY_ADDRESS2 + "," +
    KEY_CITY + 

    //KEY_ZIP +
    " from " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE +
    " where " +  KEY_SEARCH + " MATCH '" + inputText + "';";
    Log.w(TAG, query);
    Cursor mCursor = mDb.rawQuery(query,null);

    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}




}
```

Comment: no need to put it in asset folder

Answer (score 0):

> Should I place that sqlite file in assets folder?

=> There are 2 ways to manage database in Android.

1. Create fresh database through code
2. Use existing database

### Create fresh database through code:

In this method, you have to create database and tables into it through code only. I wouldn't suggest this method for novice programmer as there are chances of mistakes in code of SQLite operations.

Here is your homework: [Android database example](https://www.google.co.in/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=android+database+example)

### Use existing database:

I would suggest you to go with 2nd method as its easy, in which you can create database using some GUI tool like SQLite Manager, which can be download as Tools in Mozilla Firefox browser.

Create a database with required tables over there and place that database file in `assets` folder.

Now, you have to write a code to use this existing database. There are plenty of examples available for the same on web.

Here is your homework: [Use existing database in android](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=android+use+existing+database+in+android)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample:

DBHelper

```
package vn.mve.db;

import java.util.List;

public interface DBHelper<T> {
    boolean insert(T val);
    boolean update(T val);
    boolean delete(T val);
    List<T> getList(int type);
    T getChild(Object val);
}
```

DBHandler

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String TAG = DBHandler.class.getSimpleName();
    protected SQLiteDatabase db; 
    private final Context context;  
    private static String PACKAGE_NAME = "";
    private static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public DBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, Def.DBNAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context; 
        PACKAGE_NAME = this.context.getPackageName();
        Def.FOLDER_DB = "/data/data/" + PACKAGE_NAME + "/databases/";
        Log.d(TAG, Def.FOLDER_DB);
        try {
            this.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            this.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        context.deleteDatabase(Def.DBNAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
        // for first database;
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if(!dbExist){
            try {
                copyDataBase("db/" + Def.DBNAME);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "createDatabse -> Copy failed!");
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        } else {
            open();
            boolean isExist = false;
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select DISTINCT tbl_name from sqlite_master where tbl_name = 'config'", null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                isExist = true;
                cursor.close();
            } else {
                isExist = false;
            }
            close();
            Log.d(TAG, isExist + "");
            if (!isExist) {
                this.context.deleteDatabase(Def.DBNAME);
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "createDatabase when database has existed");
                    copyDataBase(Def.DBNAME);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "createDatabse -> Copy failed!");
                    throw new Error("Error copying database");
                }               
            }
        }
    }   
    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase(String DB) {
        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = null;
        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = null;
        try {
            myInput = context.getResources().getAssets().open(DB);

            // Path to the just created empty db
            String outFileName = Def.FOLDER_DB + Def.DBNAME; 
            myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0){
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "copyDatabase -> File not found.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "copyDatabase");
        } finally {
              //Close the streams
            try {
                myOutput.flush();
                myOutput.close();
                myInput.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }   
    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        boolean checkDB = false;
        try{
            String myPath = Def.FOLDER_DB + Def.DBNAME;
            File dbFile = new File(myPath); 
            checkDB = dbFile.isFile();
            Log.d(TAG, "checkDatabase: " + String.valueOf(checkDB));
            try {
                File fTmp = new File(Def.FOLDER_DB);
                if (!fTmp.exists()) {
                    fTmp.mkdir();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "checkDatabase" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }catch(SQLiteException e){}
        return checkDB;
    }
    public void open() {
        try {
            String myPath = Def.FOLDER_DB + Def.DBNAME;
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);          
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
            if(db != null)
                db.close();
            super.close();
    }           
    public SQLiteDatabase getSqlDb() {
        return db;
    }
    public void setSqlDb(SQLiteDatabase sqlDb) {
        this.db = sqlDb;
    }    
}
```

And here:

```
public class MVideo extends DBHandler implements DBHelper<Video> {
    public static final String TAG = MVideo.class.getSimpleName();
    public MVideo(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean insert(Video val) {
        open();
        ContentValues cValues = new ContentValues();
        cValues.put(Def.Video.ID, val.getId());
        cValues.put(Def.Video.TITLE, val.getTitle());
        cValues.put(Def.Video.THUMBNAIL, val.getThumbnail());
        cValues.put(Def.Video.DESCRIPTION, val.getDescription());
        cValues.put(Def.Video.ENGLISH, val.getEnglish());
        cValues.put(Def.Video.VIETNAMESE, val.getVietnamese());
        cValues.put(Def.Video.ISVIEW, val.getIsView());
        long result = db.insert(Def.Video.NAME, null, cValues);
        close();        
        return result > 0;
    }

    public boolean insertList(List<Video> list) {
        open();
        db.execSQL("BEGIN IMMEDIATE TRANSACTION");
        for (Video v : list) {
            db.execSQL(String.format("INSERT INTO " + Def.Video.NAME + " (\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\") VALUES" + 
                    " (\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\")",
                    Def.Video.ID, Def.Video.TITLE, Def.Video.THUMBNAIL, Def.Video.DESCRIPTION, 
                    Def.Video.ENGLISH, Def.Video.VIETNAMESE, Def.Video.ISVIEW,
                    v.getId(), v.getTitle(), v.getThumbnail(), v.getDescription(), v.getEnglish(), v.getVietnamese(), v.getIsView() + ""));
            Log.d(TAG, "insertList -> " + v.toString());
        }
        db.execSQL("COMMIT TRANSACTION");
        close();        
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean update(Video val) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delete(Video val) {
        open();
        db.delete(Def.Video.NAME, Def.Video.ID + "=?", new String[]{val.getId()});
        close();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Video> getList(int type) {
        List<Video> list = new ArrayList<Video>();
        open();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(Def.Video.GET_ALL, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                String ID = c.getString(0);
                String title = c.getString(1);
                String thumbnail = c.getString(2);
                String description = c.getString(3);
                String english = c.getString(4);
                String vietnamese = c.getString(5);
                boolean isView = Boolean.parseBoolean(c.getString(6));
                list.add(new Video(ID, title, thumbnail, description, english, vietnamese, isView));
            }
        }
        close();
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public Video getChild(Object val) {
        open();
        Cursor c = db.query(Def.Video.NAME, new String[]{
                Def.Video.ID, Def.Video.TITLE, Def.Video.THUMBNAIL, Def.Video.DESCRIPTION, 
                Def.Video.ENGLISH, Def.Video.VIETNAMESE, Def.Video.ISVIEW
        }, Def.Video.ID + "=?", new String[]{val.toString()}, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        Video v = new Video(c.getString(0), c.getString(1), 
                c.getString(2), c.getString(3), c.getString(4), 
                c.getString(5), Boolean.parseBoolean(c.getString(6)));
        close();
        return v;
    } 
}
```

And here....

```
List<Video> list = null;
MVideo mVideo = new MVideo(getApplicationContext());
list = mVideo.getList(VideoType.GET_ALL);
VideoAdapter adapter = new VideoAdapter(this, list);
if (list != null) {
    GridView gvVideo = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gv_video);
    gvVideo.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```